# Not compiling tikz-cd diagrams for drafts

Tags: tikz-cd, draft

It is possible to replace figures with placeholder boxes when compiling a LaTex document by including `draft` in the documentclass statement as so:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}
```

Is there a simple method for doing this for `tikz-cd` diagrams as well, other than encasing the diagram in a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: As per the tikz manual, have you tried
"To speedup the compilation, you may wish to use the following class option:
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}"?

Comment: Have you tried using ‘externalize’?